# how to implement printing functionality in android

Tags: android, printing

PrintManager class is add from api level 19.

how to implement printing functionality in below api level 19 in android.

Comment: Go to [how to implement printing functionality in below api level 19 in android?](https://www.google.co.in/#q=how+to+implement+printing+functionality+in+below+api+level+19+in+android.)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/printing/custom-docs.html

Comment: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Printing_with_the_Android_Printing_Framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the Android Support Libraries designed to provide backward-compatible versions of Android framework APIs as well as features that are only available through the library APIs. Each Support Library is backward-compatible to a specific Android API level. This design means that your applications can use the libraries' features and still be compatible with devices running Android 1.6 (API level 4) and up.

If you look through the revision history you can see that

```
Android Support Library, revision 19.0.1

Changes for v4 support library:

    Improved PrintHelper by adding asynchronous handling of printing.
```

You can find details of the support libraries [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is no support for printing at the OS level in Android 4.3 and below. You will need to use some sort of third-party software, such as Google Cloud Print, or perhaps an application from your printer manufacturer. Details for how to use such software should come with that software.